# Как обратиться к каждому элементу в массиве массивов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, foreach

Мне нужно обработать каждую координату, а получается что обращаюсь к первому и второму подмассиву. Подкорректируйте, пожалуйста, как надо?

```js
    let rings =   
[[2279206.7663000003, 6068865.9603 ],
[ 2279208.3274999997, 6068823.1731 ],
[ 2279207.6547, 6068793.376 ],
[ 2279205.1052, 6068771.1369 ],
[ 2279039.6064, 6068432.769099999 ]]

rings.forEach(function() {     
    let point = { x: rings[0], y: rings[1] }; 
    console.log(point)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let rings = [
  [ 2279206.7663000003, 6068865.9603 ],
  [ 2279208.3274999997, 6068823.1731 ],
  [ 2279207.6547, 6068793.376 ],
  [ 2279205.1052, 6068771.1369 ],
  [ 2279039.6064, 6068432.769099999 ]
];

rings.forEach(function(item) {     
  let point = { x: item[0], y: item[1] }; 
  console.log(point)
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, друг!)

Comment: @Igor На страже ))) Приветствую. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085886/%d0%a6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-fullpage-js/1085926#1085926

Comment: @devoid Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @Igor да-да  не забыл, там надо было 7 минут выждать прежде чем появится такая возможность)